# How to change default "migrations" table schema on postgreSQL Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I want to ask about laravel default schemas.
the first time we create a laravel project by default laravel will create us some tables like users, failed_jobs etc. what I want to ask is that the "migrations" table defaults to the public schema in postgreSQL which is different from users, failed_jobs which we can change the schema via php code, but I can't find the migration file for the "migrations" table. so I can't change the schema.

maybe someone can help with this problem? thank you

Comment: couldn't find a file here **root/database/migrations/some_date__create_failed_jobs_table.php**

Comment: @Hamelraj hello hamelraj, thanks for replying, but sorry i don't understand what do you mean. can you tell me more detail?

Comment: If you don't want failed_jobs schema you can removed file from **root/database/migrations/some_date__create_failed_jobs_table.php**

Comment: @Hamelraj i mean, i want to change schema for "migrations" table. failed_jobs can be remove/change via php code on migration directory, but not for "migrations" table